# No way to switch from RU language at enter screen

Tags: language, keyboard-layout, default

After switching to default russian, I'm stuck with ru language as start language, and no way to change it. None of regular language switching keys working( No alt+enter, shift+alt, or caps lock (which I had previously as a default for layout switching).

Since, obviously my password is in English, I'm stuck at the loading screen. 
Switching to the recovery doesn't help ether since there is no way to enter commands in russian. 
What should I do now? I'm already considering wiping clean whole disk, but that is not something I want to do, since I have some work done which I prefer to have saved.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can change the language setting:

1. change `Keyboard` Which you can change by `Alt+Shift`
2. change `input method` Which you can change by `Alt+Space`(By default disabled)

Option one is easy even you can change at login-screen, But if you changed `input-method` this you can't change at login-screen using `Alt+Space` because ibus is not running by default, to fix that issue just press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or F2 login using your credentials and install below:

```
sudo apt install ibus-m17n
```

Then reboot and you should be able to change input-method at login screen using `Alt+Space`

Comment: That would've worked if my credentials were in Ru. But they are not. So, no matter if I enter them inside of a regular terminal or on a login screen - the input is in russian, and I simply can't login. Both ways that you've provided for switching the layout doesn't work, that's the point, and I've written about it in my question!